# jQuery get closest DROPDOWN(SELECT) element with ID

Tags: jquery, web, client-side, development-environment

**Hi All**
I am trying to get the closest dropdown element with a Id on it,
On a page I am having 2 elements with same Id attribute, 
now I want to select the closest one when I click any element in the page

```
<select id="XYZ" .... >
<bla bla bla OTHER DOM ELEMENTS>
<select id="XYZ" ... >
<bla bla bla OTHER DOM ELEMENTS>
<btn="ABC" />
```

when I click the button I want to get the VALUE of the closest SELECT element

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Do you mean closest previous or next `select`? Eg, if I clicked the first `bla` element, should it return the first or second `select`?

Comment: when I click the button, it should return me the closest SELECT value, adding to the above the SELECT elements can be anywhere down, up anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You really should not have two elements with the same ID on one page, since it is against the HTML specification and can cause problems.

Instead, consider using a class and separate IDs if necessary, and selecting with jQuery:

```
<select class="XYZ" id="select_1" .... >
<bla bla bla OTHER DOM ELEMENTS>
<select class="XYZ id="select_2" ... >
<bla bla bla OTHER DOM ELEMENTS>
<button id="ABC" />

<script>
$(function()
{
    $('#ABC').click(function()
    {
        var value = $('#select_2').val();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Id user class instead and then find closest element,
jquery will not work properly when there will be more then one element with same id.

and in your html parent and child element are looking like at same level if so then use siblings instead of closest.

Comment: yeah with the class I can select by $(element).closest('.abc').val()); but I am compelled to use Id here boz I am a same model for both the views, 1 view is in the razor view and the other is rendered through light box

Comment: so forced to use Id's here

Comment: in case of same id jquery will not give required result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .prev as shown below

```
   $(this).prev().attr('value');
```